# Increasing Array's values in Java

Tags: java

Why this code doesn't add "1" to array's values?
(I have written it by "Enhanced For Loop"; when I wrote it with "old For", it worked.

```
public class EnhanceForLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

            System.out.println("List before call addOne");
            printList(list);

            System.out.println("Calling addOne");
            addOne(list);

            System.out.println("List after call addOne");
            printList(list);
    }               

    public static void addOne(int[] list) {
        for (int val : list) {
            val = val + 1;
        }
    }

    public static void printList(int[] list) {
        System.out.println("index, value");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ", " + list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the for-each doc: _"Therefore, the for-each loop is not usable for filtering. Similarly it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it."_ In short, use the for-each when you perform a read-only operation.

Comment: You have misunderstood the purpose of enhance for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not increasing array values.Do

```
public static void addOne(int[] list){
     for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                list[i] = list[i] + 1;
         }
}
```

Below statement

```
val = val + 1;   //will not increase array value it will increase val value
```

Comment: user is trying by pass by value, not by reference. So, it wont increment. Just check it

Comment: Thank you. So, we cannot use "Enhanced For Loop" for increasing values of array, right?

Comment: @ViswanathD *"Just check it"* Yes, you should do that.

Comment: @Shirin we can use any iterating process, but the incrementation should be done on original field (list) not on passed by value.

Comment: @Shirin yes in your case `val` does not denote array reference

Comment: @deogratias: why we can use that "identifier (val)" to sum all array's values, but cannot use for increasing them?

Comment: @Shirin `val` is a primitive type. It contains just a number, nothing else. If you use a enhanced for loop, then `val` will carry the current value of an array index. So you can use it to sum the array values. But `val` has no clue which array index it was (to put it simply), so it cannot change a value in the source array. If you had an array of mutable object types, then you could call methods on `val` to change the state of the object on the currently selected array index.

Comment: @Shirin sorry for replying late, array represent the address in memory(as pointer in C)  when array is initialized a sequence of memory block is created where `array[1]` represent first position of that address and so on.When you say `array[1]+1` it says increase at that reference if you do `val=array[1]` and then do `val=val+1` this means that val doing operation on its own memory address value and not in array's memory address

Answer (score 1):

The value you are increasing is for the declared variable `val`, which is disconnected copy of array's currently iterating index variable.